A mixed race bar owner in Brooklyn tells the story of his dad
I saw this movie in the early 1990s late one night on television. The story is about a man who is living in New York (why do I think Brooklyn?) he is working class, factory job, his wife is a striver. He meets an immigrant woman who is married to an alcoholic man, she is pregnant by an African American man, his friends are abusive to her, calling her names, he has remorse.
He basically starts to support her and eventually lives two lives. He tells his wife he is working at the factory at night, but he is seeing this other person in a parallel house and household. When the wife finds out, she is very racist toward the pregnant woman, he leaves in the end, against all odds, he finally starts his own bar business. The story is told by his son, the half black child of the German immigrant woman.
It was a great socially conscious film about ethnicity moral choices, with great actors, but no famous names that I recall. It's not Lone Star and set in the 1950s. I wish I could find it but I think it was not that popular. (The son was played by Ron Canada but he only appears at the end of the movie!)

No it is not Lone Star. It is set in NY I think in the 1950s working class white family.

A very nice ID Q, so I'm a bit baffled by the downvotes. Possible answer below.

@cde Well, I'm used to that, but didn't expect to see something like this at 0. It's well-put and contains everything.

Maybe I should not use the word "race?" it might have triggered some downvotes. It's a good film. Cut it out!!

You're basically describing Two Family House, but a couple of things are a bit off: It's from 2000, the immigrant couple is Irish and I don't think it stars Ron Canada. But the rest is pretty accurate.

An unseen narrator (who we gradually come to learn is telling the story of his mother and step-father's romance) looks back to the year 1956, in the Elm Park neighborhood of Staten Island, New York, to one Buddy Visalo (Rispoli), an Italian [factory worker] with "Ralph Kramdenesque" dreams. [...]
Buddy decides to buy a dilapidated two-family house in the Irish section of town, intending to live upstairs with his wife Estelle and run a bar downstairs [...] He discovers, to his dismay and her horror, that the upstairs Irish tenants, a drunken, violent older man (played by Kevin Conway) and his very pregnant young wife (played by Kelly Macdonald of Trainspotting fame) refuse to move and won't pay rent.
When the baby is born, it's clear his father was black – and the much older, drunken Irish husband immediately skulks off, knowing it's not his child. Buddy evicts mother and child, then feels guilt and sets her up in a flat while she sorts out an adoption. Estelle's lack of faith, the small-minded prejudices and low ambitions of his “friends,” the Irish lass's spirit, Buddy's dream, racial prejudice, and the baby's fate play out in an engaging story with real chemistry between the leads and a message that ultimately exemplifies a Joseph Campbell-like "Follow your bliss."

Much like Goodfellas, the movie stars many actors from The Sopranos. Here's the trailer:




That's the one. boy did I get some things wrong! I wonder if it is as good as I "recall" it! Thanks!!
